# Shutter snapshot to set pixel size for `pixelize tool`?

Tags: shutter

I'm a new Ubuntu Desktop user and looking for snapshot tool to use as alternative to Greenshot in Windows.

I found Shutter is the one. Though when using `pixelize tool`, I want to make pixel size to be bigger/smaller as in Greenshot, and I cannot find where to do so.

So where can we set pixel size for `pixelize tool`?

Comment: You seem to be trying to educate yourself on your chosen tool via AskUbuntu. That's not why we're here. Have you tried the terminal commands `man shutter;man Shutter` (I don't know which is the typo, but Linux IS case-sensitive) and `man pixelize` and `man -k shutter`?

Comment: What you mean by "educate yourself"?

Comment: I mean that you should read the `man` pages I suggested above, and not ask simple "How do I use it" questions here. Your questions show absolutely no effort on your part.

Comment: Thank you. I think your judge is incorrect since I am the one who not simply asked.

Comment: About manual document I searched on Shutter official site which seems to be abandoned